# Mix between Half Notes and Eighth Notes: What Kind of Note is This?

Tags: notation, sheet-music

I came across these weird looking little dudes in a horrendous Trombone concertino that my orchestra is swallowing whole:

[image]

I apologize for the crummy image. I refer to the strange hybrid-looking things starting at the 4th measure of rehearsal E.

Comment: @guidot Absolutely it is. The wording is different. Let's see what I can do...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect they are [tremolos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tremolo#Notation); specifically, slow ones. That's why there's only one beam, rather than the two or three that you would normally see.

I've generally understood that three beams = demisemiquavers, two beams = semiquavers, and one beam = quavers. Here's a visual example that I stole and cropped slightly:

[image: Tremolos]

Source: https://musescore.org/en/node/67246

Comment: It is definitely an indication for a trem.